# Android - sync sms/calls on web

Tags: android

i'd like to store my sms/call on the remote database. My Q is more of architecture design than actual code.

I'd like to use broadcast receiver to catch sms/call immediately. Can broadcast receivers invoke time consuming actions such as connecting to remote DB?

And there is also possibility of no internet connection at the moment. so probably the best idea would be to use local sqlite as buffer for records and then dump it on the remote db. So the next question is - what use for dumping local sqlite to remote db? some background service and timers or another broadcast receiver which waits for internet state change.. or combination of both?

And final Q is which method use to contact remote db? throu direct login into remote sql or throu http posts + php + json.

so the workflow would be like: event -> broadcast receiver -> local SQLite -> (?receiver/service?) -> (?direct conn/http+php+json?) -> remote db

Answer (score 1):

> Can broadcast receivers invoke time consuming actions such as connecting to remote DB?

Yes. Not required in your case.

> what use for dumping local sqlite to remote db?

In regular intervals it can dump it to remote db. Also before the regular interval if a call or event arises, during that time also you can dump both saved events and live event. Its like combination of both.

> which method use to contact remote db?

Through interface like php, XML, json, posts. Because in future you can even change the db. SO it doesn't need to change client.